A particular construction involving squares on triangle sides and power of a point calculation
This is a problem readapted by a contest. Consider a triangle $ABC,$ with sides $a=BC, b=AC$ and $c=AB.$ On each side erect a square, lying on the half plane cointaining the triangle: denote the various vertices as in the attached picture. Let $P$ be the intersection between $A_1A_2$ and $B_1B_2;$ let $Q$ be the intersection between $A_1A_2$ and $C_1C_2.$ Finally consider the line through $P$ perpendicular to $AB$ and the line through $Q$ perpendicular to $AC:$ you know that these lines intersect in a point $X.$ You want to calculate the power of $X$ with respect to the circumcircle $\Gamma$ of $ABC:$ in the figure I have denoted with $Y$ the intersection, different from $A,$ of line $AX$ with this circle, and then with these notation I want to compute $AX\cdot AY.$
———————————
What I have done so far:
Using GeoGebra and working a little bit it seems like the point $X$ is the reflection of the centroid $G$ of $ABC$ with respect to the circumcenter $O,$ and using this fact the answer can be computed easily: $X$ and $G$ have the same power, and using some known formulas about the Euler line we get
$$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{9}$$
I don’t know how to prove the fact in a simple way (in coordinates it’s a bad computation, and I would like to avoid this path). The only thing I have proved are the following:

Denoting with $R$ the intersection of the lines $B_1B_2$ and $C_1C_2,$ by construction the triangles $ABC$ and $PQR$ are orthologic: I have also proved that the medians of $ABC$ are perpendicular to the sides of $PQR,$ hence the orthology centers are the point $X$ and the centroid $G$ of $ABC$
We have $\angle{C_1CA}=\angle{BCC_2},$ since they are both complementary to $\angle{ACB};$ similar relations hold consider the angles on the other two vertices of the triangle

Do you have any idea on how to prove this fact? Or is there another simpler way to calculate the power of $X?$

EDIT
I add the proof that the two triangles $PQR$ and $ABC$ are orthologic: to do that I can prove that the medians of $ABC$ are perpendicular to the sides of $PQR.$ Below there is the proof that line $AG$ is perpendicular to $PQ,$ the same reasoning applies to prove that $BG\perp PR$ and $CG\perp QR.$ If we consider triangle $AA_1A_2$ and we rotate it counterclockwise of angle $90$ degrees with center of the rotation in $A$ then $A_1$ goes to $C$ while $A_2$ goes to the point $H$ symmetric of $B$ with respect to $A.$ In this way we have that line $AM,$ where $M$ is the midpoint of $BC,$ is parallel to $CH;$ but also by construction $CH$ is perpendicular to $A_1A_2=PQ,$ hence the statement.



Note that the square doesn't lie in the interior of the triangle, so that phrasing of "erect a square, lying interior to the triangle" should be clarified. It is possible that the contest simply used this sloppy language and provided a diagram.

While I agree coordinates is likely complicated, did you try complex numbers? The vertices of the square have nice representations (EG $A_2 = a+ i (b-a)$), so we should be able to get nice-ish values for the intersection $P$. To verify the claim that $X = - (a+b+c) / 3$, it remains to show that $XP = ki (b-a)$ (and bolsters my hope that $P$ has a nice form, which I leave to you to calculate).

I’m sure that the construction is that in the picture. Maybe I can clarify the statement saying that the squares are erected on the sides of the triangle, each one in the half plane containing the triangle, thanks. About the second statement, yes I tried a little and in this way I can conclude (even if the calculation for $P$ and $Q$ may seem not so short), but I was curious to see if a synthetic solution was possible… just another thing, in your expression for  I suppose ,, are the complex numbers associated to the vertices, not the sides of the triangle as in the statement, right?

FYI: Although certainly a good question for Math.SE, this might also be well-received by the Euclid Geometry Research Mailing List on Groups.io. Its members include frequent contributors to the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers.

Right, $a, b, c$ are complex numbers associated to the vertices. $\quad$ Can you add your complex-number solution as part of showing your work? esp since I consider that a simple way.

I have stopped in calculating the vertices of the squares, as you wrote for $A_2,$ then I stopped the computation, because for $P$ and $Q$ it seemed to me that the thing was becoming really heavy, even putting $A=0$ to simplify and $B$ on the real axis (the previous comment maybe is misunderstanding, I meant that I think I can conclude in this way, but I actually didn't finish the computation...)

Can you elaborate on how you concluded that $PQR$ and $ABC$ are orthologic? In particular, are you assuming that $XR \perp BC$? Note that $X$ is only defined as the intersection of those 2 lines. $\quad$ However, if you have indeed separately shown that $AG \perp PQ$, then we can apply the symmetry property of orthologic triangles.

I have added the proof that $AG\perp PQ,$ which also applies to prove that the other medians of $ABC$ are perpendicular to the other sides of $PQR...$
